# Equivalent of select/remove for Mathematica?

Tags: expression-manipulation, maple

What is the Mathematica equivalent of Maple's [`select`/`remove`](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=select)?

To quote Maple:

> A typical application that uses select and remove is to split the
> factors of a product, `e`, into those which depend on a variable `x` and
> those which do not (that is, constants). This can be accomplished by
> using `v := select(has,e,x)`; followed by `c≔remove(has,e,x)`. It is more
> efficient, however, to use `v,c≔selectremove(has,e,x)`.

For example:

```
selectremove(has, c^2 + 2*c*x + x^2 + 1, x)
                             
(* 2 c x + x^2 ,   c^2  + 1 *)
```

in an expression, not list

Thanks

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2076992).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy) for this purpose. For example:

```
SelectRemove[list_, pred_] := Lookup[GroupBy[list, pred], {True, False}, {}]
```

Using kglr's example:

```
SelectRemove[{foo[{{{{x}}}}] y^2, Sqrt[a + x^3], Log[z + 1]}, Not @* FreeQ[x]]
```

> {{y^2 foo[{{{{x}}}}], Sqrt[a + x^3]}, {Log[1 + z]}}

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[selectRemove]
selectRemove = Through[(Select /@ {#[#3], Not@* #[#3]}) @ #2] &;

has = Not @* FreeQ[#] &;

poly = c^2 + 2 c x + x^2 + 1;

selectRemove[has, poly, x]
```

> ```
> {2 c x + x^2, 1 + c^2}
> ```

```
selectRemove[has, poly, c]
```

> ```
> {c^2 + 2 c x, 1 + x^2}
> ```

```
selectRemove[has, poly, 2 c]
```

> ```
> {2 c x, 1 + c^2 + x^2}
> ```

If the input expression is a list, e.g.,

```
lst = { foo[{{{{x}}}}] y^2, Sqrt[a + x^3], Log[z + 1]};

selectRemove[has, lst, x]
```

> ```
> {{y^2 foo[{{{{x}}}}], Sqrt[a + x^3]}, {Log[1 + z]}}
> ```

In this case, you can also use

```
GeneralUtilities`SelectDiscard[has @ x] @ lst

Pick[lst, Boole @* has[x] /@ lst, #] & /@ {1, 0}

Pick[lst, Boole[has[x] /@ lst], #] & /@ {1, 0} (* thanks:  b3m2a1 *)

Pick[lst, has[x] /@ lst, #] & /@ {True, False}

Through[(Cases /@ {_?(has[x]), _?(Not@*has[x])}) @ #] & @ lst
```

to get

> ```
>  {{y^2 foo[{{{{x}}}}], Sqrt[a + x^3]}, {Log[1 + z]}}
> ```

Comment: Since it seems like the OP is interested in performance, the `Pick` version could be made faster by pre-computing the `has[x] /@ lst`. Also I think `Boole` is vectorized?

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
selectremove[expr_, test_] := 
 First /@ Last@Reap[Scan[Sow[#, test@#] &, expr], {True, False}, Head[expr] @@ #2 &]
```

Tests:

```
selectremove[Range[20], PrimeQ]
(* {{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}, {1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20}} *)

has = Not@*FreeQ[#] &;  
selectremove[c^2 + 2 c x + x^2 + 1, has[x]]
(* {2 c x + x^2, 1 + c^2} *)
```

### Possible Issues

Still, implementation above isn't an exact copy of `selectremove` of *Maple*, because according to the *Maple* document:

```maple
selectremove(has, f, x)

(* undefined, y *)
```

Not sure if this behavior is worth copying though.

Answer (score 0):

This is my horrible, convoluted, ugly mess of an attempt (LOL)

sepvarx[f_] := (tmp1 = SelectRemove[List @@ f, Not@*FreeQ[x]];
Total[tmp1[[1]]])

Thanks so much for SelectRemove fn.... I woudda never worked that out from the docs

Cheers

Rich

edit: DANG! This only works for very simple expressions.... sheesh